# How to use iscsi to share disk which is CSV file system

Tags: windows, audio, cluster, sharing

I want to share folder between some windows server, but I can not use smb(cfs).
I want to use iscsi to share disk, but I donot not how to use CSV(cluster share volume) to as they file syetem to avoid to file collission.
Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

iSCSI is not a sharing protocol.  What you are doing is just connecting the "drive" to two computers at once. If you picture what is going on, it is obvious that there is no communications between the computers and no way to know what each is writing to the shared filesystem.  So they will overwrite each other and for a while just not see things but pretty quickly they will correct the drive. iSCSI itself cannot control multiple requests from the Initiators. Imagine that 3 different heads are writing the data simultaneously onto the same track of the hard drive - there will be a data mess as a result.

CSV is used only inside and between clustered Windows hosts to store cluster roles' data (VMs, FileServer folders, etc). To create a cluster you can follow the next [guide](https://www.hyper-v.io/setting-windows-failover-cluster-home-lab/)

If you need sharing - then only SMB or NFS can be used.